# Fatal Error Uncaught Exception unable to open INI file

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error, ini

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939206/calling-php-class-function-in-my-page) a few months ago about putting my DB info in an ini file and pulling that info up in my code.  Well, it is currently working on another site with the same (well, similar) code and this time, I get a Fatal Error.  The code is identical, and should work like the other one. But it doesn't.  I even moved the ini file sitting into the same directory - in case that was the issue.

```
<?php

function getConnected()
{
    $file = "connection.ini";
    if (!$settings = parse_ini_file($file, TRUE)) throw new exception('Unable to open ' . $file . '.');

    $host = $settings['mysqli']['default_host'];
    $user = $settings['mysqli']['default_user'];
    $pass = $settings['mysqli']['default_pw'];
    $dbs = $settings['mysqli']['default_db'];

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbs);  
    return $con;
}   

//MYSQLI CONNECTION
$con = getConnected();

//CONNECTION CHECK
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
?>
```

this is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open connection.ini.' in /home/ThisDirectory/public_html/dev/classes/connection.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /home/ThisDirectory/public_html/dev/classes/connection.php(18): getConnected() #1 /home/ThisDirectory/public_html/dev/classes/tables.php(2): include('/home/ThisDirectory/p...') #2 /home/ThisDirectory/public_html/dev/setup/index.php(2): include('/home/ThisDirectory/p...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/ThisDirectory/public_html/dev/classes/connection.php on line 6

Do you think it could be something like a settings/permissions issue?  I tried to give it 777, but it still didn't work.

Thoughts?

Comment: I've tried quite a few steps, and I'm still coming up short.  I don't know if there's a setting issue or a way I'm calling it `include 'connection.php';`  Should it be something else?  Again, this is almost identical to what I did with another project and I'm stumped.  ANY help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it...  The problem was my password on the DB had special characters in it without any "escape" characters.  So... yeah.  All Fixed.  I guess I'm a genius in training.