# MediaWiki w/.git:Unable to open all skins. throws uncaught exception

Tags: php, webserver, mediawiki, uncaught-exception, mediawiki-installation

'''Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to open file /skins/MinervaNeue/skin.json: filemtime(): stat failed for /skins/MinervaNeue/skin.json'''

I tried running MediaWiki 1.38 (upgraded from 1.37.x) and tried using .git. Everything went smoothly, but after configuring the install through the browser (mw-config) I went to the site and got an 500 error. I turned on error reporting and got that error above (over and over). I’m on a shared hosting provider , I can’t edit the overall config, I can alter some php.ini settings, but I think it is something simple.
I tried changing my DB password in case it was that: [Fatal Error Uncaught Exception unable to open INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618614/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-unable-to-open-ini-file)

I’ve already googled using different phrases and the exception with "php" and "mediawiki" Nothing except other fatal exception but none with failing to open a file. I’ve tried checking the permissions (directories are 755, and files are 774), checking the spelling of all the involved directories, changing the path to not use relative paths, re-downloading the skins,  and changing which version of PHP (7.4 FastCGI to 7.4) I’m using from my ISP’s control panel. Nothing worked, and for a bit I broke it so bad that I was getting blank pages, but found those errors, But I can’t find the solution to this one. I’m out of Ideas.  Help.

Comment: So, I removed the .git stuff, and I’m still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I it turns out the problem was my LocalSettings.php file was corrupted. Once I deleted the file (so it would cause mediaWiki to regenerated the file) & went into the mediaWiki setup again, and it worked as expected.